# Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace in OSGi (Karaf) with Web Application Bundle

Tags: spring-mvc, apache-karaf, karaf

I am trying to deploy the Web Application Bundle in karaf, but somehow Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace even after proper schema.

What could be the issue?

```
Karaf version : 3.0.0
Spring version : 3.2.x
Jetty version : 8.x
```

More details below:

Error while deploying:

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: 
   Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema 
  namespace   [http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc]
```

Context class

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.springframework.osgi.web.context.support.OsgiBundleXmlWebApplicationContext</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Context file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<mvc:resources mapping="/mydcos/**" location="file:/opt/mydocs/css/" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have spring-webmvc installed in Karaf. Spring DM is kinda legacy but MVC namespace handler is registered in same way as rest of them.